# how to not print a mysql table value which is equal to the the session name of the user who has logged in using a php script

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a social media prototype where user can log in, add others, send small file to others, etc. at the add friends page I have printed all the users name. when printing my name is also getting printed. what I want is to hide my my name from that list so that I get a list of all the other person except mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

`select * from table where user_name not in ($_SESSION["name"]);`

`select * from table where user_name != '$_SESSION["name"]';`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I should study MySQL again

Answer (score 0):

from php session you will get loggin user id, use that userid in your mysql query like following

```
$query = "select * from users where user_id not in(".$loggedInUserId.")";
```

where `$loggedInUserId` is the php session user id.